# Should I remove notification for NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification

Tags: ios, icloud, nsnotificationcenter

I am using this tutorial to get started:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/63269/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-2-of-2

I have use it, implemented it and test and everything is working fine.

Here I found that notification should be removed only in dealloc (at the end of the article)
 http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.com/2011/04/avoid-nsnotification-removeobserver.html

My question is should I remove notification for NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification? 
And in what method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for any notification, stop observing when you no longer care about the notification. One case where you don't care any more is when the object that is observing the notification gets deallocated.

What that second article is telling you is that `removeObserver:` is often not the best choice. It removes the observer from *all* notifications. That includes notifications that you registered for as well as notifications that the frameworks use internally. As the article explains, it's better to use `removeObserver:name:object:` to explicitly unregister for each notification. It's not telling you that you should only unregister for notifications in `dealloc`, it's telling you that you should only unregister for notifications *using the `removeObserver:` method* in dealloc. That's good advice, but it's OK to use the other remove-observer methods wherever you need to use them.

That usually means you want to unregister in `dealloc`, but it really depends on what your code does and on when you need to receive the notifications.

Comment: My confusion is this. If I need to remove it in dealloc, according to  my "business logic", why should I do it ? Because after dealloc there is no more my object, so notification can not reach it, so why to bother with removing in the first place ? Please can you clarify this for me ?

Comment: It's because you want to tell `NSNotificationCenter` that it shouldn't try to send notifications to the object anymore. You want to do that because you don't want your app to crash. `NSNotificationCenter` might be smart enough to figure this out, but if you want stable code you should make sure.